# Can all of a UIElement RenderTransform effected properties be copied into a new Element?

Tags: c#, wpf, copy, scaletransform, layouttransform

I want to make a copy of the Element that has the new properties based upon the RenderTransform.  For example, a ScaleTransform of an element on one canvas to another canvas.

```
private void CopyElement(UIElement elem, Canvas src, Canvas dest, Size scale, Vector offset) {
    ScaleTransform resize = new ScaleTransform(scale.Width, scale.Height);
    elem.LayoutTransform = resize;
    UIElement newElem = CopyElement(src, elem); 
    Canvas.SetLeft(newElem, Canvas.GetLeft(elem) * scale.Width + offSet.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(newElem, Canvas.GetTop(elem) * scale.Height + offSet.Y);
    dest.Children.Add(newElem);
}
```

Comment: You mean when there is a ScaleTransform you want to resize the element, and for a TranslateTransform "move" it somehow? How about rotation?

Comment: Yes, permanently transformed, so that all relevant properties are scaled even custom DependencyProperties (ie. LineThickness, Width, Height, FontSize... )

Comment: That's impossible with rotation. Scaling only is programming work. Multiply whatever you need by the appropriate factors.

Comment: Ignoring rotation, I'd still have to know all the properties to scale, while the ScaleTransform already seems to have done the math / coding.  There's no way to get at them?

Comment: It's unclear why you want to do this at all. If you have a problem with layout, set the element's LayoutTransform instead of its RenderTransform.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this at all.

Just set the element's `LayoutTransform` property instead of its `RenderTransform`.